# How to Export a runnable jar with Database(MSSql)

Tags: java, sql-server

when i run my programe all work fine the data base (insert ,show) but 
I want to make a runnable jar of my project with the data base(MSSQL)
when i double click on it nothing happen but when i try to execute it with the cmd to see the error this is what i got can someone tell me how to embed the database into my project or something like this (i found tutorial with other data base but i want to try it with MS SQL) thanks [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfKG5.png)

Comment: SQL Server is a client-server database, not an embedded database. You'll need something like sqllite to run the database within your jvm.

Comment: so if i use SQL server i will never be able to use it in my runnable jar or exe in other machine ^^ ?

Comment: The error (in attached image) suggests that JVM is not able to find the class `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`. You can package the dependent jars while building your jar.

Comment: can you tell me how please Siva Kumar ^^

Comment: You can run your SQL Server client program on any machine that has network access to your SQL Server, which can be on a separate client computer, a server, or in the cloud.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/

Comment: i did like you told me i package it and know i have another error https://ibb.co/c3FBTL

Comment: ahh i got it how its work for the client server thanks david but still having issue even with sql in my computer